# How to get next data set with seek pagination?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

I am trying to sort while paginating with keyset pagination (seek pagination). However, one of the fields isn't UNIQUE and can only be true/false (0/1). In keyset pagination you get the last id from one query, and use it to the next page, right? How would I approach this situation?

I start with:

```
select * from foo order by admin desc, name asc limit 3
```

it returns

```
admin name
1     a
1     b
1     c
```

Then again I should do the query, only with parameters

```
select * from foo where (admin, name) > ('1', 'c') order by admin desc, name asc limit 3
```

However this returns nothing!

How can I fix this behaviour, making it bring?

```
admin name
0     a
0     d
0     x
```

Data below for better context:

I have this table

```
foo(
 name varchar
 admin varchar(1) (0 or 1)
);
```

I have this data

```
admin name
1     a
1     b
1     c
0     a
0     d
0     x
```

when I run this query

```
SELECT * from foo 
order by admin desc, name asc
```

with this index

```
b-tree(admin desc, name asc)
```

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: I think this is perfect, the problem was at the mixed ordering (DESC and ASC), so knowing what (admin, name) > (a, b) really means was essential. SELECT (*) FROM foo WHERE ((admin < '1')
  OR (admin = '1' AND name > 'c'))
ORDER BY admin desc, name asc

This is the tweaked query to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `admin` is numeric, you could use

```
WHERE (-admin, name) > (-1, 'c')
```

That should work fine if there are no NULLs in the columns.

For keys that are strings, look at [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/245792/176905) and its answers.

To avoid gaps, make sure to include the primary key in the `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: I mistaken the field type, its actually varchar, but that's nice also, thanks! (Even I get confused on this column design)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast Admin from '1', '0' to boolean and sort on NOT ADMIN::boolean. Or even convert the column from text to boolean.

```
-- set up 

    create table foo( admin text, name text);

    insert into foo(admin,name)
       values ( '1', 'a'), ( '1','b'),( '1','c')
            , ( '0', 'a'), ('0','b'),('0','c')
            , ( '1', 'g'), ( '0','d'),( '1','e')
            , ( '1', 'x'), ( '0','y'),( '1','z')
            , ( '1', 't'), ( '0','4'),( '1','7');

    -- Function to return data for Next_Page
    create or replace function next_page(in last_foo foo)
      returns refcursor
     language plpgsql strict
     as $$ 
     declare 
         ref refcursor;
     begin
        open ref for  
           select * from foo 
            where (not admin::boolean, name) > (not last_foo.admin::boolean, last_foo.name)
            order by not admin::boolean, name
            limit 3;
        return ref;
    end;
    $$;



    -- demo 
    select true > false, '1' > '0';
    --- test, Individual selects for each page with known results 
    select * from foo;
    select * from foo order by not admin::boolean, name;
    select * from next_page();   
    select * from next_page(('1', 'b'));
    select * from next_page(('1', 'g'));
    select * from next_page(('1', 'z'));
    select * from next_page(('0', 'b'));
    select * from next_page(('0', 'y'));


    -- test routine for continuous paging
    do $$
    declare 
       frec_cur   REFCURSOR;
       frec foo ;
       frecp foo;
       l_had_rec boolean;
       l_page_num integer = 0;
    begin
       frecp = ('1','')::foo;
       loop
          l_had_rec = false;
          l_page_num = l_page_num + 1; 
          raise notice '--- Page %  --------------------------------', l_page_num;
          frec_cur = next_page2(frecp); 
          loop
              fetch frec_cur into frec;
              exit when not found; 
                 l_had_rec = true;
                 raise notice 'Admin: %, Name: %',frec.admin::text, frec.name; 
                 frecp = frec;
          end loop;
       exit when not l_had_rec;
       end loop;
       raise notice '*** End of Data ***' ;
    end ; 
    $$;
```